# Displaying new lines in HTML textarea when data is retrieved via ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I'm trying to load text into a text area via ajax. The text is in a JSON document, so I am retrieving something that looks like this:

```
{
    "message" : "Line1\nLine2\nLine3",
}
```

I then try to set the text like this:

```
$('#my-textarea").text(myJSON.message);
```

However, the '\n' characters are not showing up as line feeds.

Anyone have any idea how to go about showing this text properly when the text needs to be set with JavaScript?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Use val instead of text

```
$('#my-textarea').val(myJSON.message);
```

JSFiddle attached:

http://jsfiddle.net/A4MTf/1/

Comment: I've actually tried this, but it's not working as it is in the JSFiddle... I even tried copying and pasting the response text from Chrome's Network tab, and its working in the fiddle but not on my page. Very strange...

Answer (score 0):

if the following works fine for you

```
$('#my-textarea").text("Line1\nLine2\nLine3");
```

then it means you have '\' symbol encoded, so you just need to replace encoded value with \ by javascript before assigning the value.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to replace \\n with \n:

```
message = message.replace(/\\n/g, '\n');
```

Not sure why I didn't think of this earlier...

Comment: This is exactly what I meant. I'm glad it helps to you.